# Comment ID in Comment field

Tags: entities, comments

I've added a custom static field to comments. This static field is custom php code but I need to access the specific comment ID using php code in it. So how can I get the comment ID for every comment in the static php field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 you can use the below code to get all the comments of a node using node ID

```
 $nid = 2;    
 // you can get nid 
 // $node = menu_get_object();
  //  $nid = $node->nid;
    $comments = db_select('comment')
              ->fields('comment', array('cid'))
              ->condition('nid', $nid, '=')
              ->execute()
              ->fetchAssoc();
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
        print your comments here
    }
```

Also you can check below links
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_get_thread/7

In Drupal 6 you can use the comment_render() ;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i need to get a specific ID. Ok let's say that the static php field will display a submission(check) button on every comments. This submission button should send via POST the relative comment ID. How can I do that? Thanks again.

Comment: do you have any specific data by which you want to get cid ?   you can use comment_get_thread() function to get all the comment of a node and then you can get comment id by filtering using comment value(title)

Comment: No. I mean I've added this php "button" as a field on every comment and I need to get the cid of the comment the button is on(something like a Token to access). I don't know if I've been clear, my english is not the best in the world. But thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry I left your comment unreaded. With the title, the problem is the same: how can I get the single comment title in php(the static field php) programmatically to filter the cid?

Comment: $subject ='comment title';                           $comments = db_select('comment')
              ->fields('comment', array('cid'))
              ->condition('subject', $subject, '=')
              ->execute()
              ->fetchAssoc();
    foreach($comments as $comment) {
        print your comments here
    }

Comment: here you will get the comment id by using comment title

Comment: Ok probably my english is not so good. $subject should be dynamic, should change on every comment. There isn't any specific 'title', I should access the title of the comment on which the static field is (repeated on every comments). Let's say I click on the button which is on comment with cid 56 and title 'Test'. The php code in the button should get cid 56 using title 'Test'. Or just get cid 56. Thanks. Tell me if i need to be more precise.